# Serving Swagger-UI in JHipster servers and microservices

Tags: swagger, microservices, jhipster, swagger-ui, springfox

JHipster servers and microservices don't serve their own Swagger UI. Instead the microservice gateway aggregates all api-docs and serves them in one place, using a custom Swagger UI within the Angular Frontend.

But when using standalone JHipster servers or microservices, there is no frontend and thus no Swagger-UI at all.

In those instances, how can you force the server or microservice to serve its own Swagger-UI?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2990#issuecomment-325214162 otherwise stay with a monolith